# How to access image files out side document root in php5/Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, file, filesystems

How can I access an image existing out side of my document root. I give direct path 
Like this

`D:/folder/image.jpeg`

But its not displaying. I am using windows OS. My server is LightTPD. My image folder not under any server. Its just inside one folder of my D drive.

I try to create one desktop application using php and jquery. So I am doing like that. Actually I will mount this image folder in a virtual space from there I need to read files. Now for testing purpose I am directly create one folder and creating my application.

Comment: Is there any reason not to copy these images under your webroot? There is a way by proxying requests to those resources with php and sending these resources as a response. But that is dangerous, as minor mistakes could probably lead to leaking many if not all information from your webserver.

Comment: What webserver are you using ? you could create an alias to that directory in your web server configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what web server you are using - but for Apache you could create an alias :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/www/mywebsite"
ServerName mywebsite
Alias   /files  "D:/folder"
```

For Lighttpd use the following syntax :

```
alias.url = ( "/files" => "d:/folder" )
```

Comment: Does it possible to do with Lighttpd server?